# Magento stock sync using a lot of memory- what options do i have to reduce memory usage?

Tags: magento-1, performance, stock

I have a file of around 100,000 sku's that need to have their quantity updated in Magento.

For speed reasons, I am doing a few things:
1. I am generating an array of SKU, Product ID and SKU so that I don't have to do a call for each product to find the product ID from the SKU code, or to get the current quantity.
2. The current quantity from above is then compared to the quantity in the file. If it is the same, then no update occurs.
3. We are using a multi warehouse plugin and so I also keep a list of the cataloginventory_stock_item `item_id` so that I can just call the model and update it.

My issue is, is that the process is using almost 2GB of memory. I can't quite see why. The file that I am reading line by line is only 5MB. I run the following functions and put the results into an array which must be where the memory is getting used.

```
protected function _getStockItemsAsArray() {
    $stockCollection = Mage::getModel("cataloginventory/stock_item")->getCollection();

    $out = [];
    foreach ($stockCollection as $stock) {
      $product_id = $stock->getData("product_id");
      $warehouse_id = $stock->getData("stock_id");
      $stock_item_id = $stock->getData("item_id");
      $qty = $stock->getData("qty");
      $is_in_stock = $stock->getData("is_in_stock");

    $out[$product_id][$warehouse_id]["stock_item_id"] = $stock_item_id;
    $out[$product_id][$warehouse_id]["qty"] = $qty;
    $out[$product_id][$warehouse_id]["is_in_stock"] = $is_in_stock;
  }

  return $out;
}

protected function _getCurrentStockAsArray() {
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource");
  $readConnection = $resource->getConnection("core_read");

  $query = "
    SELECT
      p.sku,
      p.type_id,
      w.stock_id,
      SUM(IFNULL(pe.qty,0)) pending_qty,
      SUM(s.qty) on_hand_qty
    FROM
      " . $resource->getTableName("catalog_product_entity") . " p
    CROSS JOIN
      " . $resource->getTableName("cataloginventory_stock") . " w
    INNER JOIN
      " . $resource->getTableName("cataloginventory_stock_item") . " s on
      s.product_id = p.entity_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        oi.product_id,
        oi.stock_id,
        IFNULL(SUM(qty_ordered),0) qty
      FROM
        " . $resource->getTableName("sales_flat_order_item") . " oi
      INNER JOIN
        " . $resource->getTableName("sales_flat_order") . " o ON
        oi.order_id = o.entity_id
      WHERE
        o.tigers_export_status IN('Incomplete', 'Failed', 'Pending', 'Exporting')
        AND o.status NOT IN('canceled', 'closed')
      GROUP BY
        oi.product_id,
        oi.stock_id
    ) pe ON
      pe.product_id = p.entity_id
      and pe.stock_id = w.stock_id
    WHERE
      p.sku IS NOT NULL
      OR p.sku != ''
    GROUP BY
      p.sku,
      p.type_id,
      w.stock_id
  ";
  $data = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

  $out = [];
  foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
    $out[$value["sku"]][$value["stock_id"]]["on_hand_qty"] = (int)$value["on_hand_qty"];
    $out[$value["sku"]][$value["stock_id"]]["pending_qty"] = (int)$value["pending_qty"];
    $out[$value["sku"]][$value["stock_id"]]["type_id"] = (int)$value["type_id"];
  }
  return $out;
}



protected function _getSkuToProductIDAsArray() {
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource");
  $readConnection = $resource->getConnection("core_read");

  $query = "
    SELECT
      sku,
      entity_id
    FROM
      " . $resource->getTableName("catalog_product_entity") . "
    WHERE
      sku IS NOT NULL
    ";
  $data = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

  $out = [];
  foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
    $out[$value["sku"]] = (int)$value["entity_id"];
  }
  return $out;
}
```

What other options are available to use **less memory but still have similar performance**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the database adapter method `fetchAll()` to fetch large result sets will definitely cause a heavy demand on system and resources.**

Your code may execute for a very long time and PHP will probably run out of memory if you're fetching a large amount of data.

You can fix this inefficient memory utilization by replacing:

```
$data = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
$out = [];
foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
```

By:

```
$data = $readConnection->query($query);
$out = [];
while ($value = $data->fetch()) {
```

This way, **each database row is fetched separately using the `fetch()` method to reduce resource consumption**.

The database server will execute only one query and the database buffer will be used for retrieving records one by one.

Comment: So although this will reduce the memory used by this function.. I'm not sure if it will make a difference for the whole process. Basically what is happening is that Linux is killing the process after it has loaded about 1/4 of the products. This function above only runs once, so i'm sure it would use alot of memory, but wouldn't PHP release that memory once this function has completed?

Comment: @Lock it will make a difference for sure. For example, in this simple benchmark with 200k random records, `fetchAll` uses 100249408 bytes where using `fetch` will use 440bytes, see the huge improvement that is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2771563/1038727

Comment: Thanks Raphael, but I suppose my point is that once the array has been loaded (after the function has completed), the memory usage should be the same (as that function has finished and whatever memory it was using has been released)? I made that change and it seems to be getting "Killed" by linux much sooner now. Weird. There is definitely something weird going on from a memory usage point of view here.

Comment: @Lock well your `$out` array will be the same. The huge difference here is you don't have to deal with a second massive array `$data` as this variable now stores a single entry at a time

Comment: Ok got ya. Makes sense. But $data will be released after the function exits so if I am running out of memory after this point,  then I've still got problems.

Comment: @Lock yes I reckon you should try to debug using `Mage::log()` and `memory_get_usage()` to log the memory usage and see when it starts increasing

Comment: Thanks alot! I implemented that change in 3 different places and the memory sits at a consistent level now.